# How do I select all rows from two clustering columns in cassandra database

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0, spring-data-cassandra

I have a Partion key: A

Clustering columns: B, C

I do understand I can query like this

```
    Select * from table where A = ?
    Select * from table where A = ? and B = ?
    Select * from table where A = ? and B = ? and C = ?
```

Now I have a scenario where I need to fetch results from only B and C. Is there a way to this with out using Allow Filtering.

Comment: Do you mean that you have only filtering conditions on `B` and `C` and no condition on `A`? Or do you mean that you want to project `B` and `C` columns in the result? Can you clarify this in your question and preferably give an example with some data?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot fetch on basis of 'B' and 'C' (`the clustering columns`) without partition key without using `Allow Filtering`. Though you can use spark and spark-cassandra-connector for filtering out the results on basis of 'B' and 'C'. Behind the scene it also used allow filtering but it has efficient mechanism to scan the table the right way.